# Using jabber as a cruisecontrol publisher

Tags: xmpp, cruisecontrol

I have set up the following publisher in CruiseControl:

`<jabber  host="my.network.local"

port="5222"
username="cruisecontrol"
password="cruisecontrol"
recipient="builds@conference.my.network.local"
chatroom="true"
buildresultsurl="http://cruise.control.net:7070/dashboard/tab/build/detail/customer" />`

If I set chatroom to FALSE and enter a single recipient, everything works great. The problem I have is sending sending the build notification to a chat room. I set the chatroom value to TRUE and enter the fully qualified chatroom name I get the following error:

`2009-10-16 13:34:10,818 [Thread-70897] ERROR JabberPublisher  - Could not send message to recipient or chat room
No response from server.: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.GroupChat.join(GroupChat.java:162)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.GroupChat.join(GroupChat.java:123)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.publishers.JabberPublisher.init(JabberPublisher.java:146)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.publishers.JabberPublisher.publish(JabberPublisher.java:201)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Project.publish(Project.java:742)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Project.build(Project.java:264)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Project.execute(Project.java:147)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.ProjectConfig.execute(ProjectConfig.java:402)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.ProjectWrapper.run(ProjectWrapper.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)`

Has anyone been able to send build messages to a Jabber chatroom using this method?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Jabber with CruiseControl, but have you tried connecting to that port manually from your server running CC?

Like:

```
telnet my.network.local 5222
```

Comment: Yes, as I stated, it works if I send the notice to an individual but blows up when sent to a chatroom

Answer (score 0):

Can you log any of the xmpp / jabber packets from the client to server and back?  We can see the CruiseControl config file and the java error, but we can't see what xmpp packets are actually being sent and received.  That may be key in the troubleshooting.